# What is the motor starting current and motor stall current for BLDC

Tags: power, motor, power-electronics, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor

[image]

What is the motor starting current and motor stall current, can anyone help with equation of how to find starting and stall current of bldc motor with above information

Comment: The motor starting current and motor stall currents are both mentioned on the motor datasheet, or at least the motor winding resistance is, and from that you can calculate the stall current. Please provide the motor datasheet, or at least the motor make and model number. Failing that, find (possibly by measuring) the resistance of the windings of the motor, as the input voltage divided by that resistance gives the stall current (which is also a good rule of thumb for the starting current).

Comment: its hoverboard and i use its motor, there is no datasheet provided

Comment: With above information? You can't.  However you may reasonably guess it's in the region of 5-10x the rated current which is easy to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

With a brushed DC motor, it's relatively easy. One way to express it is that you measure the resistance of the motor, and calculate the stall current. However, as the resistance of brushes varies somewhat with current, you need the resistance at the stall current, so to get that accurately, you end up measuring the stall current anyway. But however you do it, it depends only on the motor itself.

With a BLDC motor, you never connect it directly to the battery, you always use it via an ESC. How the motor starts up depends how the ESC has been programmed.